Receiving data with TCP from ANPR camera in Python
i want to receive data from This Milesight trafficX camera which has this option in Post setting :
.
i already managed to get data from HTTP section simply ran an http server and inserted the http server IP address and port in the camera setting and i was receiving it (thanks to mdonkers), but as you may know its just plain text(no security or encryption) so i wanted to give TCP a try but i couldn't accomplish anything yet.
I have tried some many codes like this :
import socket

target_host = "Camera IP"
target_port = 50000

#creating socket object
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#connecting the client
client.connect((target_host, target_port))

while True:
    #receiving the data 
    response = client.recv(4096)
    print(response.decode())

but it just not nothing anything, idk what im doing wrong, maybe the whole way of doing it is wrong idk.
EDIT:
a document i have found from manufacturer but don't know if it helps link

TCP itself isn't encrypted either. you should contact the manufacturer to receive documentation of this feature and support in using it. -- "keeps doing anything" is incorrect english. either it's "not doing anything", or it's doing "something". the word "anything", without the "not", has a distinct meaning. the "not" is not optional, if you want to express the lack of something.

Thanks for the grammar, edited question. i have found this Documentation and its about the exact part but i cant figure it out, do i need to make packets myself with the commands included in first part of the doc?

yes, that should help you implement the messages they expect to exchange over TCP. originally you wanted to go that way because you found HTTP insecure. I see no mention of encryption here, so why bother? it'll be as secure as HTTP, which is "not secure".

so you say neither HTTP, TCP or MQTT, give me any more security?
if thats true so i`ll go with bargain the complete SDK from company i think

@ChristophRackwitz Im sorry to bother more but im assuming you know more so here i am asking again, in this picture at the beginning of the docs i can see login requests, doesn't that mean it has a layer of security so i need user and password to authenticate myself in camera dashboard before receiving any messages?

MQTT can use encryption. HTTPS (note the S) uses encryption. TCP itself does not. I did not read the entire document you linked. a login request doesn't mean any of that communication is actually encrypted. does it say "TLS" or "SSL" anywhere?

No it Didn`t, thank you in advance. i think I'm gonna leave it as http for now.
